# Android .2.2 not supporting java below 1.8 and appengine not supporting java 1.8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, android-studio-2.2

Android 2.2 not supporting java below 1.8 and appengine not supporting java 1.8.
Then how can work with both together

Comment: adding 
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
in dependencies make it compile .

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
dependencies {
   sourceCompatibility = 1.7
   targetCompatibility = 1.7
}
```

in build.gradle help it to run with java 1.7
make it work